# How-to align ListPlot with ArrayPlot and Label some Points

Tags: plotting, visualization

I would like to overlay `ListPlot` on `ArrayPlot`. I have explored a number of posts, but I did not manage to achieve the desired outcome. Hence, the reason for the post. Following is a visual representation of what I want to achieve.

[image: matrix]

1. Set custom axes;
2. Align `ArrayPlot` to `ListPlot` axes;
3. Plot points with labels;

Here is the grid I would like to overlay...

```
colors = RGBColor /@ {"#c7e8ac","#ffeca9","#ff8f80"}

grid = {
{Yellow,Yellow, Red, Red, Red},
{Green, Yellow, Yellow, Red, Red},
{Green, Yellow, Yellow, Yellow, Red},
{Green, Green, Yellow, Yellow, Yellow},
{Green, Green, Green, Green, Yellow}
} /.{
Green-> colors[[1]]
, Yellow-> colors[[2]]
, Red-> colors[[3]]
};

ArrayPlot[
 grid
 , Mesh -> True
 , Axes -> True
]
```

and the data would be generated in the following way...

```
Outer[{#2, #1, #1*#2} &, Range[0.01, 1, .01], Subdivide[1000, 20000000, 1000]] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

I have tried to implement a solution using `Epilog` and `Inset`. However, the results are suboptimal...

[image: matrix]

The code used for the above...

```
ListPlot[
 {{5000, 0.05}}
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 10^6}, {0, 1}}
 Epilog -> Inset[
   ArrayPlot[
    grid
    , Mesh -> True
    ]
   , Scaled[{0.02, 0.02}]
   , Scaled[{0, 0}]
   , Scaled[1]
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: does `ListPlot[{{{5000, 0.05}}, {{500000, 0.7}}}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"Label 1", "Label 2"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[Large]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10^6}, {0, 1}}, 
 Prolog -> 
  Inset[ArrayPlot[grid, Mesh -> True, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
   Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[1]], AspectRatio -> 1]` give anything close to what you need?

Comment: @kglr hello, and yes!

Comment: w.doroskevic, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Use the option `AspectRatio -> 1` in `ListPlot[...]`, (2) use `Prolog` (instead of `Epilog`) so that the points and lines are not covered by inset object, (3) add the options `PlotRangePadding -> None` and `ImagePadding -> None` to `ArrayPlot`:

```
lp = ListPlot[{{{50000, 0.05}}, {{500000, 0.7}}}, 
  PlotLabels -> {"Label 1", "Label 2"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[Large]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10^6}, {0, 1}}, 
  Prolog -> 
   Inset[ArrayPlot[grid, Mesh -> True,
           PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None], 
    Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[1]], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Post-process to change the styling of callout lines:

```
lp /. {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4], ___], ___} :> {} /. 
 b_BSplineCurve :> {Black, b}
```

[image]

Comment: For completeness, could you please adjust the `Ticks` for both `x` and `y` axes as in the picture posted as the desired outcome? I am anticipating alignment issues there, and I would appreciate if you could advise on that.

Comment: @e.doroskevic, looks like the ticks in your posted picture are not linearly scaled.

Comment: I can appreciate this complecates matters. Any advice how this could be incorporated into the model above?

Comment: You might consider  using the option [ScalingFunctions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) with `ListPlot`, or, using  [ListLogLinearPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogLinearPlot.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer provided. After reading the documentation for the `Scaling Functions`, I remain unsure how to fix the axes. I will spend some time on it, and hopefully come up with a solution.